# How to read a particular value from a web page in Python/Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I want to read the amount value (24.40) from this HTML.

```
<div id="order-total" class="clear-fix" style="margin-bottom:20px;">
    <h3 class="col-left">Order total</h3>
    <h3 class="col-right" style="display: block;">
    <span class="credit-total-to-order" data-total-to-order="24.40">$ 24.40</span>
    credits
    </h3>
</div>


xpath - /html/body/div/header/section/form/div[5]/h3[2]/span
css - html body.ui-lang-en div#slave-edit.string-v2 header#slave-edit-header.edit
      section#order-form form#frm-order-translation div#order-total.clear-fix 
      h3.col-right span.credit-total-to-order
```

I know I should use `find_element_by_class_name` or `find_element_by_css_selector`.
But not sure what should be the argument.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

Why not select the value from the element and parse the string to get the answer you need. For example, you can split the string and disregard the dollar to return the number you need.

```
someString = selenium.find_element_by_css_selector(".credit-total-to-order").text
someString.split(' ')[1]
```

Bear in mind - this will *only* work for the example you have provided.

Comment: Just to be clear - when using a css selector the dot notation indicates that you are looking for a classname, so .someClass finds the element with the class="someClass"

Comment: it is a selenium method that extracts the text from the element and passes it into a variable, thus someString contains the value       "$ 24.40"

Comment: I got this error. `NoSuchElementException: Message: u'Unable to locate element: {"method":"class name","selector":".credit-total-to_order"}'`

Comment: That's because there's a typo in my solution... fixed now

Comment: Error again: `ElementNotVisibleException: Message: u'Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with'`

Comment: Silly question but... Are you sure the element is visible on the page?  If it isn't visible, Selenium can't use it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20578/discussion-between-cba-and-cppcoder)

Answer (score 1):

Its not necessary to use `find_element_by_class_name or find_element_by_css_selector`..You can achive it with xpath like this

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='credit-total-to-order']").text
```

**UPDATE:**

As per your updated html it looks like the style makes your element hidden.Mean while I also came to notice that the value you want to get is also stored in an attribute data-total-to-order.

So you can do somthing like this :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='credit-total-to-order']").get_Attribute("data-total-to-order")
```

Comment: Same error : `ElementNotVisibleException: Message: u'Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with'`

Comment: Could you please paste your complete html code for better undrestanding?

Comment: Added the html source of that component.